# start and bind to the same service

Tags: android, android-service

I am a little bit confused about starting a service and also bound to it. Accordingly to [Android developers - Manage Service Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Lifecycle) if you start a service and also bind to it when you call stopservice, only if all activities that have [bound](/questions/tagged/bound) to the service have unbound from it, the service will be stopped regardless you have called [stopservice](/questions/tagged/stopservice). I thought that if you call stopService the service is being stopped immediatly. In my activity i start the service and bound to it only from this activity. So when i want to stop the activity i also have to call unbind from it first?

Answer (score 0):

You should call unBind on the service instance on the onDestory() method of the activity which is bound to the service.This is usual precise for binding and unbinding service.If you are binding it in activity's onCreate() you must unbind it in onDestroy().

Comment: You are right but what am i asking is when i call stopService regardless the binded activities the service should be stopped

Comment: you can think your service as a task that executes .So you can stop the service from any of the component that is bound to it.Stopping a service will stop the execution of service but it will not unbind it.So when you call stopService it will just stop the execution and when you want to execute the service again you can start service again.